# How to limit _id field to return in MongoDB use Thinkphp/PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, thinkphp

I use Thinkphp to develope a web project.Now i need query the mongodb with specified fields and suppress the '_id' field.But the '_id' field is include in result set by default.I know in mongodb client can use follow code to suppress '_id' field,but what about use PHP/Thinkphp？

```
db.inventory.find( { type: 'food' }, { _id:0 } )
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809975/how-to-remove-a-document-referenced-by-an-id-in-mongodb-from-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MongoModel to query, usage like Mysql Model.

`M('CollectionName')->where(array('type'=>'food'))->field('_id')->select();`