# Unable to delete MongoDb document with Php

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to delete a record from mongodb database using php by passing mongodb ID. The code executes fine but it's not deleting the specified document, does anyone see any problem with the code below ??

```
    $postData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

    $conn = new MongoClient();
    $db = $conn->selectDB('employees');
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'employees');
    $emp = array('id' => new MongoID($postData['$id']), true);

    try {
        $collection->remove($emp, array('justOne' => true));
    }
    catch (MongoCursorException $e) {
        die(json_encode(array('message' => $e->getMessage())));
    }

    echo ('The employee has been deleted successfully');
}
```

Comment: Should it be `_id` instead of `id` => `$emp = array('_id' => new MongoID($postData['$id']), true);` ?

Comment: Tried that as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe, there's a problem with class named **MongoId**. Make sure what the type of "id" is. It must be same. For reference refer [delete mongodb document with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809975/how-to-remove-a-document-referenced-by-an-id-in-mongodb-from-php). I hope it'll help you to understand.